# how to load image in custom list-view from another activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-imageview

I have a 7 images in one activity, when i click any of the image it changes it's background color to show effect to user, now what i want to do is when user click any image and press submit button i want to get that image to next activity and show it in image-view.

[image]

So in above activity i have image like Mon,Tue etc...

So in my next activity i have Custom list-view with one check-box, image-view and text-view so basically i want to show that particular image inside list-view's image-view so how can i achieve this.

Below is my code.

```
notappl.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notappl.setImageResource(R.drawable.na_press);
            computer.setImageResource(R.drawable.computer);
            piggy.setImageResource(R.drawable.piggy_bank);
            book.setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
            maths.setImageResource(R.drawable.mathsicon);
            dna.setImageResource(R.drawable.dnaicon);
            brain.setImageResource(R.drawable.brain_icon);
        }
    });

    computer.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notappl.setImageResource(R.drawable.na);
            computer.setImageResource(R.drawable.computer_press);
            piggy.setImageResource(R.drawable.piggy_bank);
            book.setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
            maths.setImageResource(R.drawable.mathsicon);
            dna.setImageResource(R.drawable.dnaicon);
            brain.setImageResource(R.drawable.brain_icon);
        }
    });
```

and so on for all the images

**MyListModel.java**

```
package iqualtech.skirr;

public class List_ClassModel {

private String class_name;
private int class_ID;

public List_ClassModel() {
}

public List_ClassModel(String class_name) {
    this.class_name = class_name;
}

public String getClassName() {
    return class_name;
}

public void setClassName(String class_name) {
    this.class_name = class_name;
}

public int getClass_ID() {
    return class_ID;
}

public void setClass_ID(int class_ID) {
    this.class_ID = class_ID;
}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class Custom_ClassAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

List<List_ClassModel> rowItems;

public Custom_ClassAdapter(Context context, List<List_ClassModel> rowItems) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTextView;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_class, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.classImage);
        holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.classname);
        holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
    holder.mCheckBox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Code.classDel = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    Log.d("sdfdsf", "sdfsdf");
                }
            });

    List_ClassModel rowItem = (List_ClassModel) getItem(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(rowItem.getClassName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

public void clear() {
}
}
```

**CustomClass.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/assignmentheader" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classname"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/classImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `holder.mImageView .setImageResource(rowItem .getClass_ID())`

Comment: @Raghunandan, Thank you for quick reply, but what should i have to pass inside my image-view click event.

Comment: you can use intent and pass the id to next activity to display image there

Comment: My all images click event like notappl or computer etc etc..., or any other change because i just created code for changing background color of images that's it. So how it will take that image with the code which you have provided.

Comment: i really don't understand your comment. can be little more specific and explain with clarity

Comment: Ok sorry for that, What i am trying to say is if i want to pass this image to other activity then i must have to pass some reference, so how can i pass that reference that it show that particular image with that ID.

Comment: using intents as i just mentioned `intent.putExtra("key",rowItem .getClass_ID());`

Comment: I am really not getting you. Means where is the code to pass intent???

Comment: set tag to button. in on click use get tag then use intent.

Comment: Can you give any working example because i am really stuck in this and not getting how to do.Please help...

Comment: `notappl.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,SecondActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("key",R.drawable_na_press);
               startActivity(intent); 
        });`

Comment: But i don't want to start new activity by clicking any of the image... Because i have to perform other operation after clicking this button.

Comment: then you requirement is not clear and it is a bad design.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44886/discussion-between-innocent-killer-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 0):

Simply get that Image url ..

Save that to string ..

And then on click pass that to another activity using bundle ..

Fetch that url in other activity and do what ever you wish.

**UPDATE**

On click of button pass your value like ..

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            your_image.putExtra("valueq", R.drawable.app_icon);
            startActivities(intent);
```

And when you need to retrive that in new Class ..

```
imag_link = getIntent().getIntExtra("valueq", value);
```

Make sure that you are passing a int value so you need to get that in new class like that only.

That's it.

Comment: Hope ... that you are getting url from server ?

Comment: No, i am just getting image from drawable folder.